# Find the smallest number $\alpha$, such that for all $x,y,z$ $\alpha(x^2-x+1)(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)\ge(xyz)^2-xyz+1$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, optimization, contest-math, fractions

> Find a smallest number $\alpha$, such that for all $x,y,z$ (not all of which are positive) inequality
> $$\alpha(x^2-x+1)(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)\ge(xyz)^2-xyz+1$$

#### My work so far:

Let $f(t)=t^2-t+1$. Then $f(t) \ge \frac34$.

If $x=0, y=z=\frac12$, then $$\alpha\ge \frac{16}9$$

Comment: Now I understand where I have made an error: the domain where we look for a solution is $D=\mathbb{R} \backslash (P)$ where (P) is the positive octant. Thus the minimum could occur either inside (P) (but this is not the case) or on its boundary. Here we have to inspect three subcases : either it is on a face of (P) (z=0 or y=0 or x=0, as the example given by @Roman83, or on an edge (x=y=0 and $z \neq 0$), or at the origin (which gives also 16/9).

Comment: I think, the answer is $1+\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg that answer would mean all variables are positive, which the OP has excluded.

Comment: Dear @Macavity ! What is your counterexample? Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg To get the answer of $1+2/\sqrt3$, I think we must have $x=y=z>0$. But then all variables are positive, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Macavity if one of variables is negative so the inequality with $1+\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$ is obviously true

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg The inequality being true is fine, but you never have equality, so that doesn't give the smallest $\alpha$.

Comment: @Macavity we need that the inequality is true for all reals variables. For $\alpha=1+\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$ the equality occurs, when $x=y=z=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt3+\sqrt[4]{12}+1)$. I don't see any problems.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I understand what you're saying, but the question seems written wrong then. "Not all variables positive" is specifically mentioned.

Comment: @Macavity I think it was a typo. He wanted to say "not all of them can be positive"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the starting formulation the answer is $\frac{16}{9}$.

If $x$, $y$ and $z$ are non-positives so after replacing $x\rightarrow-x$...
we need to prove that 
$$\frac{16}{9}(x^2+x+1)(y^2+y+1)(z^2+z+1)\geq x^2y^2z^2-xyz+1$$

which is true for all non-negatives $x$, $y$ and $z$ because we'll prove now that even
$$\frac{16}{9}(x^2+x+1)(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)\geq x^2y^2z^2+xyz+1$$.

If $x\leq0$, $y\leq0$ and $z\geq0$ we need to prove that
$$\frac{16}{9}(x^2+x+1)(y^2+y+1)(z^2-z+1)\geq x^2y^2z^2-xyz+1$$ 
for non-negatives $x$, $y$ and $z$, which follows from
$$\frac{16}{9}(x^2+x+1)(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)\geq x^2y^2z^2+xyz+1$$
again.

Now we'll prove it:

$$\begin{align}
&16(x^2+x+1)(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)-9(x^2y^2z^2+xyz+1)
\\&\phantom{aaa}=(16(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)-9y^2z^2)x^2+(16(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)-9yz)x
\\
&\phantom{aaaaa}+16(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)-9
\\&\phantom{aaa}
\geq\left(16\left(\frac{3}{4}y^2+\left(\frac{y}{2}-1\right)^2\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}z^2+\left(\frac{z}{2}-1\right)^2\right)-9y^2z^2\right)x^2+
+(3y\cdot3z-9yz)x
\\&\phantom{aaaaa}+
16\left(\frac{3}{4}+\left(\frac{1}{2}-y\right)^2\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}+\left(\frac{1}{2}-z\right)^2\right)-9
\\&\phantom{aaa}\geq0
\end{align}$$

Comment: Nice +1.  Though I think you will not get equality with at least one variable negative, so $\alpha > \frac{16}9$, or there is an infimum (as say $x \to 0^-, y, z = \frac12$), not a minimum.

Comment: Indeed, in the case $x\leq 0$, $y\geq 0$, and $z\geq 0$, the equality holds iff $x=0$ and $y=z=\frac{1}{2}$.  What if we allow $x,y,z$ to be positive at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

From your
$a(x^2-x+1)^3\ge x^6-x^3+1
$,
since
$(x+1)(x^2-x+1)
=x^3+1
$
and
$(x^3+1)(x^6-x^3+1)
=x^8+1
$,

$a(\frac{x^3+1}{x+1})^3\ge \frac{x^9+1}{x^3+1}
$
or
$a\ge \frac{(x^9+1)(x+1)^3}{(x^3+1)^4}
$.

According to Wolfy,
this has a maximum of
$2.1547$
at $x \approx 0.435421
$
and
$2.29663
$.
These are the roots of
$0
= x^6-2 x^5-x^4+x^2+2 x-1
$.

The exact roots are
$-1, 1,
\frac12 (1\pm\sqrt{2} 3^{1/4}+\sqrt{3}),
\frac12 (1\pm i\sqrt{2} 3^{1/4}-\sqrt{3})
$.

So $a$ must be at least
$2.1547$.

Comment: I think, it's WolframAlpha's solution. It's not your solution.

Comment: Ah, the joys of management.